# Why doesn't createNativeQuery return a TypedQuery<T>?

Tags: java, jpa, generics, suppress-warnings

When I try to do a TypedQuery of a type that is generic, I get a unchecked type conversion warning from Eclipse.

I am using a generic here because in the dataset, every year has to be separated into a different table due to time constraints on queries and edits. There are 118 years of data in the table (since 1900), and I would like to build a system that can extend itself every year using the Java Reflections API. However, this means that prior to compilation, my parent classes don't know which child class or table they will be operating on.

Here is an example of some code that will cause an unchecked warning even though I'm specifying what type everything is through a TypedQuery. The code I have will compile and run just fine on my database.

```
public class MyParentRepository<T extends MyParentPojo>
{
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   private Class<T> tea;

   public MyParentRepository(Class<T> tea)
   {
      this.tea = tea;
   }

   public void giveWarning(int year)
   {
      String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM mytable%d t", year);

      TypedQuery<T> resultSet = (TypedQuery<T>) em.createNativeQuery(sql, tea);
   }
}
```

The expected result is that since tea is guaranteed to be instantiated with the generic type , as it's the same type everywhere and once instantiated it can't be changed, so the compiler should understand that the Entity Manager is going to return a TypedQuery of type  as well. However, it results in an unchecked type warning even though it's guaranteed to work.

I've seen people suggest fixing an unchecked type warning by going from a Query to TypedQuery, but that isn't helping in this case. Is there a way to avoid this warning while still doing what I am trying to do?

In response to an answer that was deleted, I would like to clarify something.

```
em.createQuery(String)
em.createQuery(String, Class<T>)
em.createNativeQuery(String)
em.createNativeQuery(String, Class)
```

1. Of these options, the first takes in a JPQL string and returns a
   generic Query.
2. Option 2 takes in a JPQL string and a specific class representing a table 
   row, and returns a TypedQuery.
3. Option 3 takes in a SQL string and returns a generic Query.
4. Option 4 takes in a SQL string and a specific class representing a table row, 
   and why does it return a generic Query and not a TypedQuery?

It seems to me that if I am giving it a POJO of the appropriate type, option 4 should figure out how to serialize it like Option 2 does for me. In fact it does, but it doesn't set the type correctly like Option 2. This is not acceptable from my point of view since not every SQL query can be represented by a JPQL query, so there may be times I need to use SQL, and I would expect to have a TypedQuery returned.

I've solved the warning I had by switching to option 2, but I still would like to know the answer in case as I said, a situation arises where I cannot use Option 2 in the future.

Comment: Where are you getting a warning exactly?

Comment: Ok, someone deleted an answer that turned out to be very useful, even if it didn't directly answer the question here. I have a new question now. Why does EnityManager's createNativeQuery(String, Class<T>) return a Query and not a TypedQuery<T> when createQuery(String, Class<T>) returns a TypedQuery<T>. What this means is that either I have to go through unnecessary steps to explicitly cast the results into T, or I have to deal with a warning in my code. Also, should I update this question with this, or create a new question along these lines?

Answer (score -1):

Its because `createNamedQuery` returns `Query` not `TypedQuery<T>` even in "typed result" variant.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html

Comment: Thank you for at least trying, but I even said as much in my question. Perhaps you know why they decided to return a normal Query rather than TypedQuery<T>.

Comment: This answer just rephrases the question title with changing 'why' to 'because'.

Comment: @PetrAleksandrov thats correct, but take into account that title was changed AFTER iv posted that answer.